# binomial tree number of nodes

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

Does anybody knows that how we can assign number to nodes for binomial tree . I mean how we can represent the number of nodes by array? please give me hint I am really confused .

Comment: I don’t understand your question at all. Perhaps you could give an example?

Comment: What do you mean by binomial trees?

Comment: I want to create a binomial tree then number its node and then represent the tree by array that array index represent the number that we have specified to node .

Comment: The problem here might be one of terminology: if you mean a tree for which every node has zero, one, or two children, many people refer to those as $binary$ trees.

Comment: @RickDecker - maybe OP means this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap

Comment: I have problem for index of this kind of tree , do I have to convert it to binary tree ?

Comment: @HEKTO Could be.

Answer (score 0):

In a binary tree, you can represent the tree from root to leaves as follows:

0 root
1 2 root's children
3 4 5 6 root's grandchildren
etc.

To get the children of a node, you take its index x and compute 2x+1 and 2x+2.

This makes some certain assumptions: Each node has exactly two children, except the leaves, which are all on the same (or two neighboring) levels. If a level is not full, it is filled from left to right.

Comment: you mean representing of a binomial tree is by binary tree ?

Comment: I thought you meant binary tree. I don't know what you mean by binomial tree, sorry.